# Semaphores and Threading VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am attempting to create a race condition to better understand how threading works with semaphores.  I have taken the Semaphore Class example from MSDN and modified it slightly to run in a console application.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Module Module1


    Public Class Example

        ' A semaphore that simulates a limited resource pool.
        '
        Private Shared _pool As Semaphore
        Private Shared _sharedInteger As Integer = 0

        <MTAThread> _
        Public Shared Sub Main()
            ' Create a semaphore that can satisfy up to three
            ' concurrent requests. Use an initial count of zero,
            ' so that the entire semaphore count is initially
            ' owned by the main program thread.
            '
            _pool = New Semaphore(0, 3)

            ' Create and start five numbered threads. 
            '
            For i As Integer = 1 To 5
                Dim t As New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf Worker))
                'Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf Worker)

                ' Start the thread, passing the number.
                '
                t.Start(i)
            Next i

            ' Wait for half a second, to allow all the
            ' threads to start and to block on the semaphore.
            '
            Thread.Sleep(500)

            ' The main thread starts out holding the entire
            ' semaphore count. Calling Release(3) brings the 
            ' semaphore count back to its maximum value, and
            ' allows the waiting threads to enter the semaphore,
            ' up to three at a time.
            '
            Console.WriteLine("Main thread calls Release(3).")
            _pool.Release(3)

            Console.WriteLine("Main thread exits.")
            Console.ReadLine()
        End Sub

        Private Shared Sub Worker(ByVal num As Object)
            ' Each worker thread begins by requesting the
            ' semaphore.
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} begins " _
                & "and waits for the semaphore.", num)
            _pool.WaitOne()

            _sharedInteger += 3

            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} adds to count of {1}.", num, _sharedInteger)
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} releases the semaphore.", num)
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} previous semaphore count: {1}", _
                num, _
                _pool.Release())
        End Sub
    End Class
End Module
```

If three threads simultaneously enter the semaphore at the same time how is there no race condition for read/writing to `_sharedInteger`?  Is the function of `_pool.WaitOne()` to halt other threads from accessing anything between that function and `_pool.Release()`?

EDIT
I have also tried modifiying the worker to loop 1000000 times but no error was thrown

```
Private Shared Sub Worker(ByVal num As Object)
            ' Each worker thread begins by requesting the
            ' semaphore.
            _pool.WaitOne()
            For j As Integer = 1 To 1000000
                _sharedDouble += 1
            Next j
            _pool.Release()
        End Sub
```

In this instance wouldn't it be just as well to use a mutex?